# How to populate FlowLayoutPanel with custom controls in winforms/devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

In WPF I can use binding to observable collection, itemssource and datatemplate to fill panel with custom controls. The view is kept up to date automatically when the observable collection changes. Is there a way to achieve the same in Winforms?

I am using Devexepress where for instance data grid can be easily bound to DataTable rows.

When I want to fill a FlowLayout with usercontrols for each row in DataTable, I can of course traverse the table rows and add a control. With some extra effort, I can generalize that into a WinformsItemsSource class that, provided with factory method, will subscribe to DataTable.RowChanged and adds or removes controls from view automatically.

This however feels like I am inventing a bicycle here. Someone somewhere must have already implemented this? Is there anything in Devexpress that would do this?

Comment: `This however feels like I am inventing a bicycle here`  Welcome to WinForms.